# Conditional in Foreach Statement

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to make use of twitter bootstrap carosel in OpenCart. I only want the first banner to have the div class "active." How would I go about this?

```
<div id="homepage" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
              <div class="item active">

              <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
              <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a>
               </div>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" />
              </div>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>


        </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, use additional variable $flag

```
<div id="homepage" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <?php 
          $flag = 0;
          foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
          <div class="item <?php echo ($flag==0?"active":"");?>">

          <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a>
           </div>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" />
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php 
          $flag=1; 
          } ?>


    </div>
```

Comment: this worked brilliantly. Thank you. Can you please provide a good source to read up on foreach loops and flag variables?

Comment: Using flag variables is a common trick, not only for foreach loops. You might read more at Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_word

Answer (score 0):

You can also uses the array's key, than you can choose the first or the second etc...

```
<div id="homepage" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">

    <?php 
      $flag = 0;
      foreach ($banners as $key => $banner) { ?>
      <div class="item <?php echo ($key == 0?"active":"");?>">

      <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a>
       </div>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" />
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php 
      $flag=1; 
      } ?>


</div>
```